Adding a default image when json returns null / None
Is it possible to add a default image to this code when the result returned for avatarUrl from JSON is null?
@staticmethod
def score_to_mod(score):
    return floor((score - 10) / 2)

def __init__(self, character_id):
    self.character_id = character_id
    self.character_data = self.get_character_data()
    self.character_image = self.character_data.get("decorations", {}).get("avatarUrl", "")[:-51]
    #print(self.character_url)

def update(self):
    self.character_data = self.get_character_data()

def get_character_data(self):
    req = requests.get(f"https://character-service.dndbeyond.com/character/v5/character/{self.character_id}")
    #print("hello")
    if req.status_code != 200:
        return None
    try:
        j = req.json()
        if not "success" in j or not "data" in j:
            return None
        return j["data"]

    except ValueError:
        return None

Here is the end of the script where the data is used by my main script
return {
    "max": max_hp,
    "current": max_hp - self.character_data["removedHitPoints"],
    "temp": self.character_data["temporaryHitPoints"],
    "image": self.character_image,
    "char_id": self.character_id
}

I tried adding an "if" statement, but the result was unfavorable.
I tried adding the following code to the __init__, and when that didn't work, I tried adding it to the get_character_data
if self.character_image is None:
    self.character_image = "https://www.dndbeyond.com/avatars/39102/30/1581111423-110222058.jpeg"


So is it really None, or some other value {empty string?)

@tripleee well, that's a good question.  I haven't figured out the pythonanywhere console to print messages.  The front end browser says NoneType, and the actual page I'm pulling data from says "null".
Example of normal from source
"readonlyUrl":"https://dndbeyond.com/characters/77800426","decorations":{"avatarUrl":"https://www.dndbeyond.com/avatars/39102/30/1581111423-110222058.jpeg?
Example of not working from source
"readonlyUrl":"https://dndbeyond.com/characters/77800426","decorations":{"avatarUrl":null,

But your get will return an empty string when it's unavailable, because you wrote it so.

So typically, I would handle an empty string with == "", but that's in js.  This is python, and even more unchartered territory for me than js..  I am really hoping for some more guidance.  I've been scouring the web, and I don't think I'm phrasing the question well enough there.

Do I need to convert it to "Null" on None before I can do anything with it?

You can play with JSON and see what happens with special values before/after parsing them into Python dict using the json built-in package and an interactive Python session (+1 for iPython). To get you started, json.dumps and json.loads are useful playthings; They both work with strings (hence the s there). See what this does: json.dumps({5: None}). Then, try vise versa to answer your question about JSON's null.

There are a few guiding principals you can revolve your design around.

Separation of concerns - The algorithm to parse the response data should be in a single place. This includes parsing the response structure and handling special cases.
Exceptions are a common tool for execution flow control. Think of it as a fancier if/elif/else. And it is fancy (also, cheaper than compiled languages so no worries there). Use it to your advantage (hint: No key in the dict? No problem, flow goes x. No attribute in the object? No problem, flow actually goes x, too).
Lastly, you want your __init__ functions to do as little as possible. This will help you in the long run when you pull the gloves off and embrace writing tests. The sooner, the merrier you'll be. It's worth the hassle.

import requests


Class NoCharacterError(Exception):
    pass


class CharacterData:
    def __init__(self, image: str):
        self.image = image

    @staticmethod
    def parse_data(data: requests.models.Response):
        try:
            image = data.json()["data"]["decorations"]["avatarUrl"][:-51]
            return CharacterData(image=image)
        except (KeyError, ValueError) as err:
            raise NoCharacterError(f"Failed to parse response data into CharacterData. Error {err}. Data {data}.")
        
class Character:
    @staticmethod
    def score_to_mod(score):
        return floor((score - 10) / 2)
    
    def __init__(self, character_id, character_data=None):
        self.character_id = character_id
        self.character_data = character_data

    @property
    def character_image(self):
        if self.character_data is None:
            self.update()
        return self.character_data.image
            
    def update(self):
        try:
            self.character_data = CharacterData.parse_data(self.get_character_data())
        except NoCharacterError as err:
            print(f"Falling back to default CharacterData because {err}.")
            self.character_data = CharacterData(image="https://www.dndbeyond.com/avatars/39102/30/1581111423-110222058.jpeg")
    
    def get_character_data(self):
        return requests.get(f"https://character-service.dndbeyond.com/character/v5/character/{self.character_id}")


Bonus: @property is, roughly speaking, a dynamic getter/attribute. my_character.character_image will implicitly call that function.


More bonuses: It'll also help you if you use type hinting; e.g. def parse_data(data: requests.models.Response). Your IDE will magically auto-complete code/highlight issues. And, future you/teammates will thank you for the added readability.


Thank you for all of that.  I'll get to work on it.  I do use the data for a lot more than the image URL because I'm using it to track health of a dnd character.  It looks like the second INIT will provide what I need.  Here's hoping and thank you again.

Also from main.js, console.error(data1.error) "DnDBeyond takes no arguments"

Well, I'm trying to work through this, but I am getting on the chrome console Promise {: TypeError: Failed to execute 'json' on 'Response': body stream already read at setup (12…}
